# Slight Buzzing Noise on Bluetooth Headphones on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I just got a new pair of Bluetooth headphones for my Windows 10 pc. They work great except for a slight buzzing sound in the background. It's quiet enough that you can almost ignore it but I'd like to get rid of it if I can.

If I connect the headphones to my computer with the audio cable there is no noise whatsoever and sound awesome. Same if I connect them to my phone using Bluetooth. So the issue has to be something with my computers Bluetooth.

I didn't cheap out on the Bluetooth USB device. I've disabled audio enhancements and disabled hands-free telephony.

The noise is only there when the audio is playing. It stops a few seconds after the audio stops playing. I'm assuming that probably just means that there is no signal being transmitted.

Headphones: [https://www.amazon.com/Bluedio-Turbine-Wireless-Bluetooth-Headphones/dp/B00Q2VIW9M/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Q2VIW9M)
USB Bluetooth: [https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Bluetooth-Adapter-Raspberry-Compatible/dp/B009ZIILLI/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009ZIILLI)

Comment: This is normally caused by interference by poorly designed motherboards by most OEMs.  It also happens with USB headsets when the USB header is not shielded correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound Is this fixable? I built my computer myself.

Comment: @Ramhound I also put the USB Bluetooth adapter on the front of the pc so there is nothing in between it and the headphones.

Comment: This is my motherboard: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4953#ov

Comment: Have you tried other USB ports?  Have you tried using a powered USB Hub, by adding a USB between the device and your computer, you can normally cut the interference out.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried 3 ports (1 front 1 back). I'll try your suggestion though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both USB 2 headers are sitting right next to each other.  The USB 3 header is sitting by itself.  If you plugged your headset into a USB 2 port being in the back or front made no difference they are in the same location.

Comment: @Ramhound There does seem to be a little less noise out of the USB 3.0 port. When you said a powered USB hub do you mean a usb hub that you have to plug into AC as well? Because I used a usb cord to plug it in and it didn't change anything. I don't have one of those. I just have one that you plug into the computer and it splits it into 3 ports.

Comment: Yes; I mean an externally powered USB hub.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was fixed after updating the Realtek audio drivers for my HP Elitebook G8. My headset is the Valco VMK20.

The whine/noise was present when playing back audio from the “headset with mic” audio source. It was very annoying, and only audible when something else was playing from that audio source. The other source (a headset without mic) didn’t have this issue.

After struggling with it for an evening, the following morning I updated some drivers, and after updating the Realtek audio drivers and rebooting the windows, the problem was gone. So the issue was not in the headset, but a software problem with the drivers, apparently.

Sweet silence in the background. Bliss!